# writing to a csv file problems in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of lists that I want to write to a csv file. Its size is 2000 by 1547 (2000 rows and 1547 columns). I want to write it to the `csv` file such that the `csv` has 20000 rows and 1547 columns and the first row corresponds to the respective elements. But the problem is the instead of getting appended to each row as columns, the numbers got written as separate rows; e.g. a number 1257 in my list is written as

```
1
2
5
7
```

in the file.
I want the cell number in csv file to correspond to the indices of my list/2d matrix. 
Here is what I have now:

```
import csv
fpt=csv.writer(open('checl.csv','w'),delimiter=',')
for i in range(20000):
    fpt.writerow(Matrix[i])
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a list of lists? Try `print(type(Matrix[0]))`.

Comment: here is the output to that:<type 'list'>

Comment: What is the type of Matrix[i]? I don't see anything wrong with your code *as is* (except that you don't close the file, you should use 'with open...')

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] with a small matrix?

Comment: I created a test matrix `Matrix = [list(range(i, i+4)) for i in range(0,50, 10)]`, adjusted the range count and ran your code - it worked.

Comment: How about `print(len(Matrix[0]))`. The code works and the output suggests you only have 1 column not 1547.

Comment: As an aside, the `csv` module manages line endings on its own. You want to open the file as `open('checl.csv','w', newline='')` in python 3 or `open('checl.csv','wb')` in python 2.